# Android:No device found

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to run a project(previously working fine) in my android device ,but Eclipse shows the error no device found.I have referred other stack overflow solutions but didnt helped my cause.

My device shows USB:Connected &

USB Debugging :Connected

log cat only displays Launch cancelled.

The SDK manager has:
Google USB DRIVER : Installed and

Google API's: Installed.

I can not make out what am doing wrong ,for which the eclipse is not detecting the device.

Here is a screen-sort :

[image: a]

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @Aashish its windows 7, see the screenshot

Comment: try installing MoboRobo application here http://www.moborobo.com/

Comment: it has nothing to do with debugging enabled/disabled, the driver for your device has not been installed. for now, just restart your adb and see if your device appears in devices list

Comment: new to android will any one help me on this ADB part ?

Comment: find the adb.exe in the sdk/platform-tools folder then type the following command in a terminal window: adb.exe kill-server. after that: adb.exe start-server (http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to device manager
2. Locate nexus
3. Right click and update driver
4. Restart eclipse

It worked for me while using `Nexus 7`.

Comment: u mean Android Virtual Device Manager ?